# Image masking using css/javascript

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to transform a div into this [kind of shape](http://i279.photobucket.com/albums/kk148/Exiled_Gundam/ex-1.png) then fill it with an image? Or better transform an image to that shape? Both with CSS or Javascript. 
Then arrange multiple of them in this [manner](http://i279.photobucket.com/albums/kk148/Exiled_Gundam/ex-2.jpg)

I intend to group the shapes into several rings as per the second picture. As for the pictures, it will be dynamic, so can't really pre-cut them.

*Edit: I found out the effect I actually want. It is actually masking. In webkit, this css property: -webkit-mask-box-image works well (I can use .png image too for the mask), but when I tried masking for firefox (using .svg file generated by Illustrator), it doesn't seem to work. The same .svg file works in Chrome using -webkit-mask-box-image css property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Even without using any JavaScript or browser specific properties.

## *[demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/3786016)*

I've tested it and it works on all current versions of Chrome, IE, FF, Opera, Safari (on Windows 7).

The idea is to have multiple wheels with slices of different angles (get the angle using a skew transform; the slices are also rotated using a rotate transform). The inner wheels cover the the central part of the outer ones.

The version I've made is a pretty simple one, with two wheels, 8 images for the inner wheel (that means each slice of the inner wheel has 360°/8 = 45°) and 12 images for the outer wheel (=> each slice of the outer one has 360°/12 = 30°).

Relevant **HTML**:

```
<div class='picture-wheel'>
    <div class='outer-wheel wheel'>
        <div class='slice'><div class='bg'></div></div>
        <!-- the rest of the slices, 11 more for this demo -->
        <div class='inner-wheel wheel'>
            <div class='slice'><div class='bg'></div></div>
            <!-- the rest of the slices, 7 more for this demo -->
            <div class='cover-wheel wheel'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Relevant **CSS**:

```
.wheel {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1em;
}
.picture-wheel {
    width: 30em; height: 30em;
    margin: 3em auto 0;
}
.slices-wrapper { 
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
}
.slice {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50%; right: 50%;
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
.outer { width: 30em; height: 30em; }
.inner-wheel {
    transform: rotate(7.5deg);
    width: 21em; height: 21em;
    margin: 4.5em;
}
.cover-wheel {
    width: 12em; height: 12em;
    margin: 4.5em;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 1em;
    background: white;
}
.bg {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-position: 50% 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 8em 6em;
}
.outer-wheel > .slice {
    width: 15em; height: 15em;
    transform: skewY(60deg);
}
.outer-wheel > .slice:nth-child(2) { transform: rotate(30deg) skewY(60deg); }
.outer-wheel > .slice:nth-child(3) { transform: rotate(60deg) skewY(60deg); }
.outer-wheel > .slice:nth-child(4) { transform: rotate(90deg) skewY(60deg); }
.outer-wheel > .slice:nth-child(5) { transform: rotate(120deg) skewY(60deg); }
.outer-wheel > .slice:nth-child(6) { transform: rotate(150deg) skewY(60deg); }
.outer-wheel > .slice:nth-child(7) { transform: rotate(180deg) skewY(60deg); }
.outer-wheel > .slice:nth-child(8) { transform: rotate(-150deg) skewY(60deg); }
.outer-wheel > .slice:nth-child(9) { transform: rotate(-120deg) skewY(60deg); }
.outer-wheel > .slice:nth-child(10) { transform: rotate(-90deg) skewY(60deg); }
.outer-wheel > .slice:nth-child(11) { transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(60deg); }
.outer-wheel > .slice:nth-child(12) { transform: rotate(-30deg) skewY(60deg); }
.outer-wheel > .slice .bg {
    width: 30em; height: 30em;
    transform: skewY(-60deg) rotate(-15deg);
}
.outer-wheel > .slice .bg {
    background-image:
        url(image-for-first-slice-outer.jpg);
}
.outer-wheel > .slice:nth-child(2) .bg {
    background-image:
        url(image-for-second-slice-outer.jpg);
}
/* background images for the other slices of the outer wheel */
.inner-wheel > .slice {
    width: 10.5em; height: 10.5em;
    transform: skewY(45deg);
}
.inner-wheel > .slice:nth-child(2) { transform: rotate(45deg) skewY(45deg); }
.inner-wheel > .slice:nth-child(3) { transform: rotate(90deg) skewY(45deg); }
.inner-wheel > .slice:nth-child(4) { transform: rotate(135deg) skewY(45deg); }
.inner-wheel > .slice:nth-child(5) { transform: rotate(180deg) skewY(45deg); }
.inner-wheel > .slice:nth-child(6) { transform: rotate(-135deg) skewY(45deg); }
.inner-wheel > .slice:nth-child(7) { transform: rotate(-90deg) skewY(45deg); }
.inner-wheel > .slice:nth-child(8) { transform: rotate(-45deg) skewY(45deg); }
.inner-wheel > .slice .bg {
    width: 21em; height: 21em;
    transform: skewY(-45deg) rotate(-22.25deg);
}
.inner-wheel > .slice .bg {
    background-image:
        url(image-for-first-slice-inner.jpg);
}
.inner-wheel > .slice:nth-child(2) .bg {
    background-image:
        url(image-for-second-slice-inner.jpg);
}
/* background images for the other slices of the inner wheel */
```

---

Another slightly different enhanced version:

## *[demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/3786602)*

Comment: :D This is exactly what I'm looking for. I will try to add more wheels to it :D @ana

Comment: Oh and if it's not troubling you, can you give some explanation on how you calculate width and height for each slices

Comment: The `width`/ `height` for each slice are simply half the `width`/ `height` of the corresponding wheel

Comment: There are `12` slices for the outer wheel => each slice will have an angle of 360°/12 = 30°. I get that either by a `skewX(30deg)`, or by a `skewY(60deg)`, 60° being 90°-30° (the complementary value). I've used `skewY(60deg)`, I just found it more convenient at the moment. It's the same for the inner wheel, except I have `8` slices there => each slice will have an angle of `360°/8 = 45°`, which I got by a `skewY(45deg)`.

Answer (score 0):

Could try using the Canvas element and draw

http://jsfiddle.net/m6QgV/6/

Here's an example

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at CSS3 transformations. You should be able to use standard matrix transformations (similar to how you would in OpenGL or DirectX) to do it.